# visual studio 2010 wcf debug

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010

I have 2 virtual directory on my IIS (first for server developing and second for client devloping).

Each directory point to different folders:
    c:\Server\  -> localhost/Server/service.svc
    c:\Client\  -> localhost/Client/service.svc
(Whenever server "binaries" are stable I copy them to Client path)

My problem is that whenever I start debugger for server (where in VS I set "Use local IIS web server" to "localhost/Server/service.svc" ) the breakpoints are also hit form localhost/Client/service.svc (also when "binaries" are different).

I thing it is because debugger connect to w3wp.exe .

I tried to change AssemblyInfo.cs but that didn't help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that run both websites under the same IIS AppPool. This means that both websites run in the same process. You need to use different IIS AppPools if you want Visual Studio to debug  only Server.

Also you probably have architectural issue. Usually there is no need to have the same service.svc in client and server. 
Normaly you should have one Visual Studio solution with 3 projects configured as follows:

1. Project with Contracts (contains data and service contracts)
2. Server project with *.svc files
3. Client project that contains Server references generated for Server endpoint.

Both Client and Server reference Contracts.

Comment: Hi, thanks I will try to set up this in different IIS AppPools.
By "Client" I meant a stable server copy which is used to test Java app client side.